# Proper use of bibTeX in TeXmaker with a 'build' subdirectory

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

In Texmaker, I enable the option of "Use a 'build' subdirectory for output files".

The problem is that I don't succeed to use that option enabled and also to use bibTeX format at the same time. If I enable that option and try to use bibTeX at the same time, there is no "References" section in the pdf output file, and in the body of the text, instead of the number of reference, just the key name reference appears. For example:

Here's the code of the main file `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{r}

\begin{document}
This is the reference: \cite{kingma2014adam}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the content of `r.bib`:

```
@article{kingma2014adam,
  title={Adam: A method for stochastic optimization},
  author={Kingma, Diederik P and Ba, Jimmy},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1412.6980},
  year={2014}
}
```

Since I enable the option of a `build` subdirectory, the locations of the files (after compiling `a.tex` as `PDFLaTeX`, compiling `a.tex` as `bibTeX` and then compiling `a.tex` as `PDFLaTeX` 2 more times) are:

- `./a.tex`
- `./build/r.tex`
- `./build/build/r.log`

and there're several more files in `./build`.

The output pdf file is a single line looks like:

> This is the reference: [**kingma2014adam**].

How can I properly add the references section when also using the `build` subdirectory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether or not there exist pure (pdf)(La)TeX solution. But I had a similar problem (with `bibtex`) and fixed it by using  the script below (Windows batch) to call `bibtex`
(if needed you could easily adapt it to `biber`) and provide it to TeXmaker in place of the native `bibtex %` (or `biber %`) command:

```
@echo off
set dopause=0
set BUILDIR=e:\build
echo BIBTEX-Build %0
copy *.bib %BUILDIR% 1> nul 2>&1
copy *.bst %BUILDIR% 1> nul 2>&1
cd /d %BUILDIR%
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :bibit %~n1
goto end
:bibit
   echo ------ Processing %1 -------
      @bibtex %~n1 
      if %errorlevel% NEQ 0  ( set dopause=1 )
exit /b
:end
cd ..
IF !dopause! NEQ 0 pause ELSE PING -n 3 127.0.0.1>nul
```

This assumes that the `.bib` file(s) is (are) in the main (working) directory, and takes into account the fact that the `.bst` file(s) could also be in this directory. The processing is performed in the `build` directory, where the `.aux` file is, and where LaTeX will find the `.bbl` files at next run. The code deferred to the `:bibit` sub-script enable a convenient error handling (closing automatically only in case of successful processing).

What I'm really using is the more elaborate version below, which enables the possibility on multiple `.aux` files, some of which should be processed (in case of use of, e.g., `footbib` or `multibib`) and some other should not.

```
@echo off
set dopause=0
set BUILDIR=e:\build
echo BIBTEX-Build %0
copy *.bib %BUILDIR% 1> nul 2>&1
copy *.bst %BUILDIR% 1> nul 2>&1
cd /d %BUILDIR%
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in  (*.aux) do (
   set ext=%%~xf
   IF  NOT !ext!==.auxlock (
   sed -r -n -e "/\\bibdata\{[^\}]+\}/ s/\\bibdata\{([^\}]+)\}/\1/p" %%~nf.aux > %%~nf.bd
   )
)
for %%g in ( *.bd) do (
   IF NOT %%~zg==0 (
      call :bibit %%~ng.aux
   ) ELSE (
      echo  Skipping %%~ng.aux 
      del %%g
   )
)
goto end
:bibit
   echo ------ Processing %1 -------
      @bibtex %~n1 
      if %errorlevel% NEQ 0  (
        rem PING -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
        set dopause=1
       )
       del %~n1.bd
exit /b
:end
cd ..
IF !dopause! NEQ 0 pause ENSE PING -n 3 127.0.0.1>nul
```